# import multiple audio files in R

Tags: r, audio, import, wav

How can I import multiple audio *wav* files in R? One file can be done by using the `readWave` command as -

```
sample1 <- readWave("Sample audio.wav")
```

But not sure how to do this if the input files to process are many. please help!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r

Comment: Thank You so much!! that helped!!